# Can I restore the files I moved away with a script?

Tags: file, photo

I used a script to organize my photos but I included an asterisk(*) more and it moved every photo in a folder.
I'd like to restore the photos to where they were originally and I only have:

1. The date of the photos, so I could do it manually
2. In every folder the photos were originally I have two files:
   thumbs.db and zbthumbnail.info
   Can I restore the photos using them?

I used this script:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.JPG' | while read file; do
    pwd=$(pwd)
    yr=$(stat -f '%Sm' -t '%Y' "$file")
    month=$(stat -f '%Sm' -t '%m' "$file")
    folder="$pwd/$yr"
    subFolder=$folder"/"$month
    [[ -d "$folder" ]] || mkdir "$folder"
    [[ -d "$subFolder" ]] || mkdir "$subFolder"
    Mv "$file" "$folder/$month"
done
```